# Get range of bytes from s3 without OPTIONS request

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cors

I use `Amazon S3` as storage for my files, which connected as subdomain.

For example: base domain is **site.com**, s3 storage is **s3.site.com**. Sometime I want get a part of file (range of bytes) with ajax GET request:

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'GET', 
   url: "//s3.site.com/1.py", 
   headers: {"Range": "bytes=50-100"}
}).done(function( data ) {
  alert(data);
});
```

It works fine, I get response... But browser generate some parasitic request with type OPTIONS. As I know, it happens according to `CORS policy`. Can I avoid it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't avoid it.  It's standard and correct behavior.

Adding the `Range:` header changes a `GET` request in a way that triggers a CORS pre-flight check, which sends the `OPTIONS` request.

The request no longer qualifies as "simple" and pre-flight is required, since the request is cross-origin.

Same-origin (non-cross-origin) requests must have the exact same scheme, host, and port.  Subdomains are not exempt from this.

> Two origins are "the same" if, and only if, they are identical.

> https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6454#page-11

Comment: Requests to subdomain are cross origin too? For example: from site.com to s3.site.com.

Comment: @TyVik that is correct. Origin has no hierarchical authority concept. Updated answer with RFC citation.